# assigning a list of tokens as a row to dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to create a dataframe where the first column is a list of tokens and where additional columns of information can be added. However pandas will not allow a list of tokens to be added as one column. 
So code looks as below

```
  array1 = ['two', 'sample', 'statistical', 'inferences', 'includes']
  array2 = ['references', 'please', 'see', 'next', 'page', 'the','material', 'of', 'these']
  array3 = ['time', 'student', 'interest', 'and', 'lecturer', 'preference', 'other', 'topics']


 ## initialise list 
 list = []
list.append(array1)
list.append(array2)
list.append(array3)

## create dataFrame 
numberOfRows = len(list)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, numberOfRows), columns = ('data',    'diversity'))

df.iloc[0] = list[0]
```

the error message reads

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 6 to array axis with dimension 2
```

Any insight into how I can better achieve creating a dataframe and updating columns would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: are you about `df = pd.DataFrame({'data': list}); df['diversity'] = '?'` Actually don't use reserved words like `list` for variables!

Answer (score 0):

ok so the answer was fairly simple posting it for prosperity. 
When adding lists as rows I needed to include the column name and position.. 
so the code looks like below.

```
   df.data[0] = array1
```